# Java List to Scala Conversion Error

Tags: scala

I have a Java code base that returns me a java.util.List that I consume in my Scala layer as below:

```
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

    val myList = myServiceClient.getMyList.asScala.toList //fails here!

    println(myList)
```

I then hit the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.getSlaveList(Unknown Source)
    at Test$.main(Test.scala:35)
    at Test.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage.getHeaders(SoapMessage.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor.java:29)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Which Scala version?

Comment: I'm on 2.11.6 scala!

Comment: All I'm doing is just using Java classes generated by Apache CXF Client generator in my Scala code base!

Comment: Can you give a reproducible code snippet (with a Java collection that is causing the issue)?

Comment: According to the stack trace, I suspect you are not even making it to the conversion part. It seems to me that you are having a problem calling the web service. Are you sure you are not passing in a scala type to some java service? What happen if you remove the conversion part?

Comment: You know what, you guessed it right. I was not passing in the Java List type to the headers in the CXF library. I will post the solution soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the original problem was a couple of lines above in my code base to what I posted in my original question:

I had to do the following when I pass the List to the Apache CXF library:

```
   val headerList = Seq(
        new Header(new QName("http://www.myService.com/MyServices/", "UserName"), "", new JAXBDataBinding(classOf[String])),
        new Header(new QName("http://www.myService.com/MyServices//", "Password"), "", new JAXBDataBinding(classOf[String]))
    )

    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    proxy.getRequestContext.put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headerList.asJava)
```